# Access elements of a Matrix by a list of indices in Python to apply a max(val, 0.5) to each value without a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, indices

I know how to access elements in a vector by indices doing:

```
test = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
indices = list([1,3,5])
print(test[indices])
```

which gives the correct answer : [2 4 6]

But I am trying to do the same thing using a 2D matrix, something like:

```
currentGrid = numpy.array(  [[0,   0.1],
                             [0.9, 0.9],
                             [0.1, 0.1]])
indices = list([(0,0),(1,1)])
print(currentGrid[indices])
```

this should display me "[0.0  0.9]" for the value at (0,0) and the one at (1,1) in the matrix. But instead it displays "[ 0.1  0.1]". Also if I try to use 3 indices with :

```
indices = list([(0,0),(1,1),(0,2)])
```

I now get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(currentGrid[indices])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I ultimately need to apply a simple max() operation on all the elements at these indices and need the fastest way to do that for optimization purposes.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I access specific elements in a matrix to do some operation on them in a very efficient way (not using list comprehension nor a loop).

Comment: Today, I accidentally found the solution to your problem. See the Edit 4 in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already some great answers to your problem. Here just a quick and dirty solution for your particular code:

```
for i in indices:
    print(currentGrid[i[0],i[1]])
```

---

### Edit:

If you do not want to use a for loop you need to do the following:

Assume you have 3 values of your 2D-matrix (with the dimensions `x1` and `x2` that you want to access. The values have the "coordinates"(indices) `V1(x11|x21), V2(x12|x22), V3(x13|x23)`. Then, for each dimension of your matrix (2 in your case) you need to create a list with the indices for this dimension of your points. In this example, you would create one list with the `x1` indices: `[x11,x12,x13]` and one list with the `x2` indices of your points: `[x21,x22,x23]`. Then you combine these lists and use them as index for the matrix:

```
indices = [[x11,x12,x13],[x21,x22,x23]]
```

or how you write it:

```
indices = list([(x11,x12,x13),(x21,x22,x23)])
```

Now with the points that you used `((0,0),(1,1),(2,0))` - please note you need to use (2,0) instead of (0,2), because it would be out of range otherwise:

```
indices = list([(0,1,2),(0,1,0)])
print(currentGrid[indices])
```

This will give you `0, 0.9, 0.1`. And on this list you can then apply the max() command if you like (just to consider your whole question):

```
maxValue = max(currentGrid[indices])
```

### Edit2:

Here an example how you can transform your original index list to get it into the correct shape:

```
originalIndices = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)]

x1 = []
x2 = []

for i in originalIndices:
    x1.append(i[0])
    x2.append(i[1])

newIndices = [x1,x2]
print(currentGrid[newIndices])
```

### Edit3:

I don't know if you can apply `max(x,0.5)` to a numpy array with using a loop. But you could use Pandas instead. You can cast your list into a pandas Series and then apply a lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd
maxValues = pd.Series(currentGrid[newIndices]).apply(lambda x: max(x,0.5))
```

This will give you a pandas array containing `0.5,0.9,0.5`, which you can simply cast back to a list `maxValues = list(maxValues)`.

Just one note: In the background you will always have some kind of loop running, also with this command. I doubt, that you will get much better performance by this. If you really want to boost performance, then use a for loop, together with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) (you simply need to add a decorator to your function) and execute it in parallel. Or you can use the `multiprocessing` library and the `Pool` function, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Just to give you some inspiration.

### Edit4:

Accidentally I saw [this](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/vectors_matrices_and_arrays/apply_operations_to_elements/) page today, which allows to do exactly what you want with `Numpy`. The solution (considerin the `newIndices` vector from my Edit2) to your problem is:

```
maxfunction = numpy.vectorize(lambda i: max(i,0.5))
print(maxfunction(currentGrid[newIndices]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I specified that I do not want to use a for loop

Comment: Yes it helps a lot! Thank you very much. Do you know if it's possible to apply the max individually on each value? I guess I wasn't clear enough. I want to do something like val = max (val, 0.5) for each value at each index. Is it possible without using a for loop for optimization concerns?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the arrangement of the indices you're passing to the array. If your array is two-dimensional, your indices must be two lists, one containing the vertical indices and the other one the horizontal ones. For instance:

```
idx_i, idx_j = zip(*[(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2)])
print currentGrid[idx_j, idx_i]
# [0.0, 0.9, 0.1]
```

Note that the first element when indexing arrays is the last dimension, e.g.: (y, x). I assume you defined yours as (x, y) otherwise you'll get an `IndexError`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand using two lists is the right way to access the elements by indices. But is it possible then to do an operation on each of these elements without using a for loop? I am trying to find a less cpu intensive way to a max(val, 0.5) on all these elements

Comment: If you only care about the extracted values you can either use the `map` function or a list comprehension. Both are way faster than a `for` loop, but avoid `lambda` functions + `map` ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)). If you want to operate those values "inside" the array, `numpy` may have some function that can map a function to those positions.

Answer (score 0):

2D indices have to be accessed like this:

```
print(currentGrid[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]])
```

The row indices and the column indices are to be passed separately as lists.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, this works. But is it possible to do a max(value, 0.5) on all these elements without using a for loop?